# Chaining two XHR calls using chrome.runtime.sendMessage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension and I'm refactoring my XHR calls in to the background script to be accessed via messaging as per the [new requirements with Chrome 73](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) and up for providing XHR data to content scripts. I have two XHR calls - the first grabs the data, and the second XHR call uses a value returned from the first as part of it's query.

```js
// background.js
// First Call
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.contentScriptQuery === 'getProductData') {
      let dataUrl = C.API(request.term);
      $.ajax({
        url: dataUrl,
        type: 'get',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        dataType: 'json',
      }).then(response => response)
        .then(text => sendResponse(text))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      return true;
    }
  });

// Second Call
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.contentScriptQuery === 'getProductGroupData') {
      const dataUrl = C.PRODUCT_GROUPS_API(request.term);
      $.ajax({
        url: dataUrl,
        type: 'get',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        dataType: 'json',
      })
        .then(response => response)
        .then(text => sendResponse(text))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      return true;
    }
  });
```

In my React component, I have a method that calls these methods. In the first msg, I assign the returned data to state values. This is working as expected. However, the second msg isn't sent, and even just swapping in a log statement I can't seem to get it to fire.

```js
// Content Script
// React component. fetchData() called from inside componentDidMount()
fetchData() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      { contentScriptQuery: 'getProductData', type, term: searchTerm },
      text =>
        this.setState({
          // assign values from returned data
          superCategoryId: text.content[0].productGroupHierarchy.superCategoryId,          
        }),
    );
  
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      { contentScriptQuery: 'getProductGroupData', term: this.state.superCategoryId },
      text =>
        this.setState({
            // assign values from returned data
        }),
    );
}
```

Is there some restriction on having multiple msgs sent to a listener in the background script? The first XHR call and msg returns data, the second one does not seem to execute at all (I've swapped out the return msg with a console statement and that doesn't return either.

Comment: No such restriction AFAIK. This is something to debug in devtools. Set a breakpoint in the content script and in the background script listener, run the code, step through it line by line and inspect the variables, see what happens on both ends.

Comment: On the other hand I've never seen multiple listeners being used for onMessage so there might be a restriction - this is a simplified one-time messaging after all - or even a bug.